# All real number for which $n$ in $5^n+7^n+11^n=6^n+8^n+9^n$

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-sum

> Finding all real  number $n$ in
>
> $$5^n+7^n+11^n=6^n+8^n+9^n$$

Try: From given equation

$n=0,1$ are the solution

But i did not understand any other solution exists or not

Although i have tried like this way

$$\bigg(\frac{5}{9}\bigg)^n+\bigg(\frac{7}{9}\bigg)^n+\bigg(\frac{11}{9}\bigg)^n = \bigg(\frac{6}{9}\bigg)^n+\bigg(\frac{8}{9}\bigg)^n+1$$

Right side is strictly increasing function. but i have a confusion whether left side is strictly increasing or not

could some help me how to solve it, thanks

Comment: It is not correct that the right hand side of your equation is strictly increasing in $n$. Hint: can you say something about the maximum size of the right hand side?

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840394

Answer (score 6):

Consider the function $f(x)=x^n$ for positive $x$. Its second derivative is $n(n-1)x^{n-2}$ and therefore for $n > 1$ or $n<0$ $f$ is ***strictly convex*** while for $0 < n < 1$ f is ***strictly concave***.

Our equation is equivalent to $f(5) + f(7) + f(11) = f(6) + f(8) + f(9)$

In the convex case we have:

$f(6) = f(\frac{5+7}{2}) < \frac{f(5)+f(7)}{2}$,

$f(9) = f(\frac{7+11}{2}) < \frac{f(7)+f(11)}{2}$,

and that

$f(8) = f(\frac{11+5}{2}) < \frac{f(11)+f(5)}{2}$

So $ f(5) + f(7) + f(11) > f(6) + f(8) + f(9)$

In the concave case the same strict inequalities hold, but reversed.
Thus only n=0 or n=1 could be solutions and they both work.

Comment: You should include $n<0$ in your strictly convex case, and for the strictly concave case, $0<n<1$.  There is no assumption that $n$ is nonnegative.

Comment: I did'nt exclude n < 0 in the first place :D

Comment: Either you excluded $n<0$, or you made a mistake.  The strictly concave case is $0<n<1$, not $n<1$.

Comment: Oops good point :D thanks